# Trouble with Mapping multilevel JSON object to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an JSON data coming back from an API, I want to convert it to an array, but having trouble getting the "timeline" category into the array,

Sample JSON:

```
[{
    "id": 100,
    "key1": 310797,
    "key2": 807874,
    "key3": 24283,
    "key4": 180900,
    "timeline": {
        "createDate": "2021-04-08T22:53:23Z",
        "lastChangeDate": "2021-04-27T12:03:57Z"
    }
},
{
    "id": 101,
    "key1": 310797,
    "key2": 807875,
    "key3": 24284,
    "key4": 180903,
    "timeline": {
        "createDate": "2021-04-04T22:53:23Z",
        "lastChangeDate": "2021-04-24T12:02:57Z"
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

I am using the follow Javascript to try and parse this to an array

```
function convertToArray(json) {
    var headers = Object.keys(json[0]);
    var values = json.map(function(e) {
        return headers.map(function(f) {
            return e[f]
        })
    });
    values.unshift(headers);
    return values
}
```

This is returning:

```
[[id, key1, key2, key3, key4, timeline],
[100, 310797, 807874, 24283, 180900, ""],
[101, 310797, 807875, 24284, 180903, ""]]
```

However the Array I am trying to achieve is:

```
[[id, key1, key2, key3, key4, createDate, lastChangeDate],
[100, 310797, 807874, 24283, 180900, 2021-04-08T22:53:23Z, 2021-04-27T12:03:57Z],
[101, 310797, 807875, 24284, 180903, 2021-04-04T22:53:23Z, 2021-04-24T12:02:57Z]]
```

Any assistance with how I can map the "createDate" and "lastChangeDate" into the array would be truly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that will collect keys and values from object structures recursively:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 100,
    key1: 310797,
    key2: 807874,
    key3: 24283,
    key4: 180900,
    timeline: {
      createDate: "2021-04-08T22:53:23Z",
      lastChangeDate: "2021-04-27T12:03:57Z",
      TZ: {TZname: "GMT", TZoffset: 0} // extended example: third level object
    },
  },
  {
    id: 101,
    key1: 310797,
    key2: 807875,
    key3: 24284,
    key4: 180903,
    timeline: {
      createDate: "2021-04-04T22:53:23Z",
      lastChangeDate: "2021-04-24T12:02:57Z",
    },
  },
];

// helper function getE : "get entry"
const getE=(j,ar=[],ge)=> // gets keys or values, dependent on `j`
  ge=c=>{Object.entries(c).forEach(e=>{
     if(typeof e[1] === "object") ge(e[1])
     else ar.push(e[j]);
  }); return ar};
  
 const res=arr.reduce((a,c,i)=>( !i && a.push(getE(0)(c)), a.push(getE(1)(c)), a),[] );

console.log(res)
```

The action happens within the function `getE()`: `getE(j,ar=[],ge)` sets a scope within which `j` (the quantity to be returned) and `ar` (an array for collection) are defined.

`getE(j)` has only *one required* argument: `j`, indicating the entry part to be returned: `0` for keys, `1` for values. It returns the function (`ge(c)`) that will recursively call itself on the intially given object `c`:

Within `ge(c)` the expression `Object.entries(c).forEach()` walks through all entries of `c` and will

- either call itself with the current value part of the entry `ge(e[1])`,

  `if (typeof e[1] === "object")`is `true`
- or will add the `j`-th part of the entry (`e[j]`) to the collection array `ar`

`ge(c)` returns the collection array `ar`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and your clear description of how it works and where I went wrong. This is working perfectly

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 100,
    key1: 310797,
    key2: 807874,
    key3: 24283,
    key4: 180900,
    timeline: {
      createDate: "2021-04-08T22:53:23Z",
      lastChangeDate: "2021-04-27T12:03:57Z",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 101,
    key1: 310797,
    key2: 807875,
    key3: 24284,
    key4: 180903,
    timeline: {
      createDate: "2021-04-04T22:53:23Z",
      lastChangeDate: "2021-04-24T12:02:57Z",
    },
  },
];

// Getting keys
let keys = [];
const obj = arr[0];
Object.entries(obj).forEach((entry) => {
  const [key, value] = entry;
  if (typeof value === "object") keys.push(...Object.keys(value));
  else keys.push(key);
});

// Getting values
const values = arr.map((obj) => {
  let temp = [];
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === `object`) temp.push(...Object.values(obj[key]));
    else temp.push(obj[key]);
  }
  return temp;
});

result = [keys, ...values];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I put the timeline keys in a Set that can be used as a lookup when mapping row data and can be easily merged with he other keys for the headers

```js
const timeKeys = new Set(Object.keys(data[0].timeline));

const headers  = Object.keys(data[0])
                   .filter(k => k!=='timeline')
                   .concat(...timeKeys);

const values = data.map(o => {
    return headers.map(k => {
      return timeKeys.has(k) ? o.timeline[k] : o[k];      
    });
});

const res = [headers , ...values];


console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
const data=[{id:100,key1:310797,key2:807874,key3:24283,key4:180900,timeline:{createDate:"2021-04-08T22:53:23Z",lastChangeDate:"2021-04-27T12:03:57Z"}},{id:101,key1:310797,key2:807875,key3:24284,key4:180903,timeline:{createDate:"2021-04-04T22:53:23Z",lastChangeDate:"2021-04-24T12:02:57Z"}}];
</script>
```